# error concatenating multiindex pandas dataframes (categorical)

Tags: python, pandas

L is a list of dataframes with a multiindex on the rows.

```
pd.concat(L,axis=1)
```

I get the following error (from the `Categorical` constructor in `categorical.py`):

> TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.

It clearly has something to do with the values in my dataframe, as I can get it work if I restrict the data in some way.

E.g. all of these work

```
a=pd.concat(L[0:6],axis=1)
b=pd.concat(L[6:11],axis=1)
c=pd.concat(L[3:9],axis=1)
```

but

```
d=pd.concat(L[0:11],axis=1)
```

fails.

```
pd.concat([x.iloc[0:1000,:] for x in L[0:11]],axis=1)
```

also works. I've gone through the edge cases at which it breaks, and for the life of me, I don't see anything that could be offensive in those rows. Does anyone have some ideas on what I should be looking for?

Comment: Privet @Victor, were you able to figure this error out? I am getting the same error on some of my code, am trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @mkheifetz nope, never did figure it out, I came up with some workaround that I don't remember anymore

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue too when I did a `df.groupby(...).apply(...)` with a custom apply function. The error seemed to appear when the results were to get merged back together after the groupby-apply (so I must have returned something in my custom apply function that it didn't like).

After inspecting the extensive stacktrace provided by pytest I found a mysterious third value appeared in my index values:

```
values = Index([(2018-09-01 00:00:00, 'SE0011527613'),
                (2018-09-25 00:00:00, 'SE0011527613'),
                1535760000000000000], dtype='object')
```

I have absolutely no idea how it appeared there, but I managed to work around it somehow by avoiding multi-indexed stuff in that particular part of the code (extensive use of `reset_index` and `set_index`).

Not sure if this will be of help to anyone, but there you have it. If someone could attempt a minimal reproducible example that would be helpful (I didn't manage to).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error:

> TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.

However, there is not much material around it. Have a look what the error log states a bit further above. I have:

> TypeError: unorderable types: range() < range()
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

The clue was 'range() < range()' because I had a previous problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019434/force-pandas-to-interpret-1-2-in-column-as-string-and-not-as-range/48019616?noredirect=1#comment83013377_48019616) with Pandas interpreting '(1,2)' or '(30,31)' not as string but as 'range(1,3)' or 'range(30,32)' respectively. Very annoying as the dtypes is still object.

I had to change the column content to lists and/or drop the 'range(x,y)' column.

Hope this helps or anybody else who comes across this problem. Cheers!