# Force pandas to interpret (1,2) in column as string and not as range?

Tags: python, string, pandas, range, apply

I have this weird behaviour in a pandas Dataframe. I am using .apply(single_seats_comma) on a column with the following example content: `(1,2)`. However, it seems to return it as `range(1,3)` instead of a string `(1,2)`. Other rows have more than 2 entries as well, e.g.
`(30,31,32)`. I have a function which splits on `,` and converts each value in brackets into a new row however with `(x,x)` it breaks.

```
def single_seats_comma(row):
    strlist = str(row).split(',')
    strlist = filter(None, strlist) 
    intlist = []
    for el in strlist:
        intlist.append(int(el))
    return intlist
```

Example for 'apply':

```
tickets['seats'][:1].apply(single_seats_comma)
```

The Error output of the def is

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'range(1'
```

Trying to find a solution, I found this:

```
str(tickets['seats'][:1])
>>'0    (1, 2)\nName: seats, dtype: object'

tickets['seats'][:1].values
>> '[range(1, 3)]'
```

It works on a column if the values are just `1,2`.

Any help help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all contributors to get me closer to a solution. The solution is actually quite simple.

The challenge was that pandas interpreted (1,2) as range and not as string However, the target was to create a list of all values, originally by splitting a string on ','. Not needed!

list(range(1,2)) does the job already. Here is the example and solution:

```
list(range(11, 17))
>> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

tickets['seats'][0]
>> range(1, 3)

list(alltickets['seats'][0])
>> [1, 2]
```

So solution(s):

```
def single_seats_comma(row):
    strlist = list(row)
    return strlist

tickets['seats'].apply(single_seats_comma)
```

or

```
tickets['seats'].apply(lambda row: list(row))
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce the `range`string.
But this function should work for both cases:

```
def single_seats_comma(row):
    if type(row) is tuple:
        return list(row)
    elif type(row) is range:
        res = [row.start]
        end = row.stop - 1
        if end - row.start > 1:
            res.append(end)
    return res
```

Example:

```
>>> tickets = pd.DataFrame({'seats': [(100, 1022), range(3, 4), range(2, 10)]})
>>> tickets['seats'].apply(single_seats_comma)
0    [100, 1022]
1            [3]
2         [2, 9]
Name: seats, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Unfortunately, your solution is not quite there yet. Here some results (1, 2)>> [1, 3] // (30, 31) >> [30, 32] // (44)>>[44, 45]. Is there a way to have pandas avoid interpreting () as range?

Comment: Modified my solution.

Comment: def single_seats_comma(row):
    result = []
    if type(row) is tuple:
        return list(row)
    elif type(row) is range:
        res = [row.start]
        end = row.stop
        if end - row.start > 1:
            result = list(range(res[0], end))
        else:
            result = res
    return result

Comment: Hi Mike, needed a little modification at the end. Special cases like (17, 18, 19, 20) were showing up as [17, 20] but correct would have been [17, 18, 19, 20]. Have a look at my comment above which works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be easier to simply iterate over the elements of the row instead of converting to string then splitting. This is simple enough to use a lambda.

```
tickets['seats'][:1].apply(lambda row: [int(e) for e in row])
```